# How to route a new component in "Pages - Admin Dashboard Template" in Angular

Tags: angular, backend, angular-router

I am trying to implement a new "notification" component in the registration page and am currently getting an error in the inspect console stating:

"Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
'app-notification' is not a known element:"

I have tried placing the "app-notification.../app-notification" in multiple places, but getting the same error. At the moment, it is in my register.component.html page like so:

```
  <div class="content {{_contentClass}}">
    <app-notification></app-notification>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
```

After watching a video, it seems the developer put the code in his "app.component.html," but in the "Pages Revox Template" I am using, there is nothing in the app.component.html other than h1.

Where should I look to put this new app-notification component so that it works? I know I did not provide much information, but will definitely provide more if need be.

Here is my app.module.ts:

```
//Angular Core
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { BrowserModule,  HammerGestureConfig, HAMMER_GESTURE_CONFIG } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule} from '@angular/http';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { RouteGuard } from "./session/route.guard";
import { NotificationComponent } from './notification/notification.component';

//Routing
import { AppRoutes } from './app.routing';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

//Layouts
import { CondensedComponent, BlankComponent, RootLayout,CorporateLayout,SimplyWhiteLayout,ExecutiveLayout, CasualLayout } from './@pages/layouts';
//Layout Service - Required
import { pagesToggleService } from './@pages/services/toggler.service';

//Shared Layout Components
import { SidebarComponent } from './@pages/components/sidebar/sidebar.component';
import { QuickviewComponent } from './@pages/components/quickview/quickview.component';
import { QuickviewService } from './@pages/components/quickview/quickview.service';
import { SearchOverlayComponent } from './@pages/components/search-overlay/search-overlay.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './@pages/components/header/header.component';
import { HorizontalMenuComponent } from './@pages/components/horizontal-menu/horizontal-menu.component';
import { SharedModule } from './@pages/components/shared.module';
import { pgListViewModule} from './@pages/components/list-view/list-view.module';
import { pgCardModule} from './@pages/components/card/card.module';
import { pgCardSocialModule} from './@pages/components/card-social/card-social.module';

//Basic Bootstrap Modules
import {BsDropdownModule,
        AccordionModule,
        AlertModule,
        ButtonsModule,
        CollapseModule,
        ModalModule,
        ProgressbarModule,
        TabsModule,
        TooltipModule,
        TypeaheadModule,
} from 'ngx-bootstrap';

//Pages Globaly required Components - Optional
import { pgTabsModule } from './@pages/components/tabs/tabs.module';
import { pgSwitchModule } from './@pages/components/switch/switch.module';
import { ProgressModule } from './@pages/components/progress/progress.module';

//Thirdparty Components / Plugins - Optional
import { NvD3Module } from 'ngx-nvd3';
import { NgxEchartsModule } from 'ngx-echarts';
import { IsotopeModule } from 'ngx-isotope';
import { StepsformDirective } from './social/stepsform.directive';
import { NgxDnDModule} from '@swimlane/ngx-dnd';
import { QuillModule } from 'ngx-quill';
import { PerfectScrollbarModule } from 'ngx-perfect-scrollbar';
import { PERFECT_SCROLLBAR_CONFIG } from 'ngx-perfect-scrollbar';
import { PerfectScrollbarConfigInterface } from 'ngx-perfect-scrollbar';

//Service - Demo content - Optional
import { ChartService } from './charts/charts.service';
import { SocialService } from './social/social.service';

//Social Page - Optional
import { SocialComponent } from './social/social.component';
import { CoverpageDirective } from './social/coverpage.directive';

//Demo Pages - Optional
import { FormWizardComponent } from './forms/form-wizard/form-wizard.component';
import { CardsComponentPage } from './cards/cards.component';
import { ViewsPageComponent } from './views/views.component';
import { ChartsComponent } from './charts/charts.component';

//Dashboard Widgets - Optional
import { DashboardModule } from './dashboard/dashboard.module';

//Dashboards - Optional
import { CondensedDashboardComponent } from './dashboard/condensed/dashboard.component';
import { SimplyWhiteDashboardComponent } from './dashboard/simplywhite/dashboard.component';
import { CasualDashboardComponent } from './dashboard/casual/dashboard.component';
import { CorporateDashboardComponent } from './dashboard/corporate/dashboard.component';
import { ExecutiveDashboardComponent } from './dashboard/executive/dashboard.component';

//Sample Blank Pages - Optional
import { BlankCorporateComponent } from './@pages/layouts/blank-corporate/blank-corporate.component';
import { BlankSimplywhiteComponent } from './@pages/layouts/blank-simplywhite/blank-simplywhite.component';
import { BlankCasualComponent } from './@pages/layouts/blank-casual/blank-casual.component';

const DEFAULT_PERFECT_SCROLLBAR_CONFIG: PerfectScrollbarConfigInterface = {
  suppressScrollX: true
};

//Hammer Config Overide
//https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10541
export class AppHammerConfig extends HammerGestureConfig  {
  overrides = <any>{
      'pinch': { enable: false },
      'rotate': { enable: false }
  }
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    CondensedComponent,
    CorporateLayout,
    SimplyWhiteLayout,
    ExecutiveLayout,
    CasualLayout,
    SidebarComponent, QuickviewComponent, SearchOverlayComponent, HeaderComponent,HorizontalMenuComponent,
    BlankComponent,
    RootLayout,
    CardsComponentPage,
    ViewsPageComponent,
    ChartsComponent,
    SocialComponent,
    StepsformDirective,
    CoverpageDirective,
    CondensedDashboardComponent,
    SimplyWhiteDashboardComponent,
    CasualDashboardComponent,
    CorporateDashboardComponent,
    ExecutiveDashboardComponent,
    BlankCorporateComponent,
    BlankSimplywhiteComponent,
    BlankCasualComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    SharedModule,
    ProgressModule,
    pgListViewModule,
    pgCardModule,
    pgCardSocialModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(AppRoutes),
    BsDropdownModule.forRoot(),
    AccordionModule.forRoot(),
    AlertModule.forRoot(),
    ButtonsModule.forRoot(),
    CollapseModule.forRoot(),
    ModalModule.forRoot(),
    ProgressbarModule.forRoot(),
    TabsModule.forRoot(),
    TooltipModule.forRoot(),
    TypeaheadModule.forRoot(),
    NvD3Module,
    pgTabsModule,
    NgxEchartsModule,
    IsotopeModule,
    NgxDnDModule,
    QuillModule,
    PerfectScrollbarModule,
    pgSwitchModule,
    DashboardModule
  ],
  providers: [QuickviewService,pagesToggleService,ChartService,SocialService,RouteGuard,{
    provide: PERFECT_SCROLLBAR_CONFIG,
    useValue: DEFAULT_PERFECT_SCROLLBAR_CONFIG
  },
  {
    provide: HAMMER_GESTURE_CONFIG,
    useClass: AppHammerConfig
  }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Here is notification.component.html:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">

      <div class="alert">
        This is a test
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is notification.component.spec.ts:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { NotificationComponent } from './notification.component';

describe('NotificationComponent', () => {
  let component: NotificationComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<NotificationComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ NotificationComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(NotificationComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Here is notification.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-notification',
  templateUrl: './notification.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./notification.component.scss']
})
export class NotificationComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Comment: Have you registered the component inside the `app.module` file?

Comment: Yes, I placed it in the app.module file

Comment: Did you register it also in the entry component array?

Comment: Yes, but maybe I did it incorrectly?

Comment: could you update the question with your code for `app.module`

Comment: Yes, of course I can

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to add `NotificationComponent` to `entryComponents` & `declarations`.

```js
// in addition to what you already have
@NgModule({
  imports: [],
  exports: [],
  declarations: [NotificationComponent],
  entryComponents: [NotificationComponent],
  exports: [NotificationComponent],
  providers: [],
})
export class NameModule {}
```

Comment: @AngelloL. can you add your NotificationComponent code please.

Comment: Let me know if you need anything else

Comment: @AngelloL. I just noticed that you're using the `NotificationComponent` inside of another component(register.component). Is that in its own module or where is it registered? you can try adding `NotificationComponent` to exports also see if that resolves the error. I'll update the snippet.

Comment: I think that is the issue. I probably do not have it set up right because I am very new to Angular